# Create new div for comment

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm getting stucked on the JavaScript here. I need to create new comment box and erase the old input. I can't figure out the JavaScript.

**Directions**

1. Create an  tag and give it a class on Line 26
2. Create a click handler for button in JavaScript
3. Select the 's class in the click handler, and then get the
   value using .val()
4. Store the value in a variable so that you can use it later
   ex: `var input = $(".class").val()`
   You can also use `console.log` to double check that everything is working properly! `console.log(input)`
5. Append a new  for each new comment

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="header" class="instagram">Instagram</h1>
    <img class="post" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/garfield/images/9/9c/.028_Garfield_Odie_%26_Zachary_28_24_20_25.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/411?cb=20160521112254">

    <div class="comments">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="avatar garfield"></div>
      <div class="comment">we look awesome!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="avatar garfield"></div>
      <div class="comment">@odie</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="avatar odie"></div>
    <input class="input" placeholder="Type here">
  </div>

  <button>Post</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var header = $(".header");
header.click(function () {
  header.toggleClass("instagram");
  var brand = header.text();
  header.text(brand === "Instagram" ? "Facebook" : "Instagram");
  var input = $("input").val();
  $("button").click(function() {
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: gray;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
.container {
  width: 425px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #E8E8E8;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.header {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 56px;
  line-height: 56px;
}
.header.instagram {
  font-family: Pacifico;
}
.post {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px 5% 0 5%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.row {
  display: flex;    
  margin: 10px;
}
.avatar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.garfield {
  background-image: url('https://yiningchen.github.io/scripted/images/garfield.gif');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
}
.odie {
  background-image: url('https://yiningchen.github.io/scripted/images/odie.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
}
.comment {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 75%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
}
.add-comment {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  width: 75%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
button {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 5%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #3b5998;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
}
button:hover {
  background: #2e4c8c;
}
button:active {
  background: #2e4c8c;
  top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: `I'm getting stuck on the Java here` There is a huge difference between Java and Javascript.

Comment: All that CSS isn't that relevant... `$("button").click(function() {` was the relevant part to show here... Why it ain't posted?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the value of an input, you can use the following:

```
$('input').val(null);
```

To create an additional input, which in your case is a text box, you can do the following:

```
$('.container').append($('<input type="text" />'));
```